set min max in mui textfield type="number" using the slotprops mui v6
i'm trying to set a min max for the textfield component but i didn't find a documentation about the slotProps api
<TextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Discount %"
                    value={amount}
                    type="number"
                    slotProps={{
                      input: {min: 0, max:100 },
                      htmlInput: { min: 0, max: 100},
                    }}
                    
                  />

Note: InputProps got deprecated.

FYI based on https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field they are not recomending type="number" anymore they suggest you use Base UI NumberInput component if needed, baseUI has the ability to set min and max

Base ui number input looks a bit different from the mui textfield component design wise.

Also isn’t heavier to install also base ui?

haven't used Base UI but yes id assume its more deps, the design is different because Base UI is headless meaning you have to design it. have you tried changing to type text and using the solution linked in mui docs here https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2020/02/24/why-the-gov-uk-design-system-team-changed-the-input-type-for-numbers/

@abdelrahman-assoum Specifying the min/max via the htmlInput slot props is correct.

@RyanCogswell it didn't work for me

@Quak_2023 i mean by min max the number range not the length so the number is between 0-100 because it is a Percentage

@abdelrahman-assoum How did you go about verifying that it didn't work? It worked fine for me. Are you expecting it to prevent numbers outside of that range (because the min/max on a numeric input don't prevent the user from entering other numbers)? You should compare the behavior to regular <input> element to make sure you understand the expected results.

@RyanCogswell Yes, you're right. I chose to handle it by hard-coding the HTML input props and using JavaScript (if-else statements) to ensure that the user can't enter a value outside the min-max range.
